# Placement of objects within a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I am following along with a project [I found online for diagrams](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part) and modified one of their shapes. The goal was to place a text box around the Path geometry. Which is working thanks to some [help on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706878/3x3-grid-containing-a-path-in-the-center-fills-the-entire-grid/24709493#24709493) but now I've got this issue.

A Path is wrapped within a Grid, with another Grid within the root Grid. The second Grid contains a series of stack panels, with the their placement around Path.

```
<!-- Square Shape -->
<Grid>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ShapeInputStyle}">
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Canvas.Top="-40"
                        Canvas.Left="-20">
                <TextBlock Text="Length"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Canvas.Left="-40"
                        Canvas.Top="-20">
                <TextBlock Text="Height"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Canvas.Right="-40"
                        Canvas.Top="-20">
                <TextBlock Text="Height"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Canvas.Bottom="-80"
                        Canvas.Left="-20">
                <TextBlock Text="Height"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <Path Style="{StaticResource Square}"
            x:Name="path"
            ToolTip="Decision">
        <controls:DesignerItem.MoveThumbTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Path Style="{StaticResource Square_DragThumb}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </controls:DesignerItem.MoveThumbTemplate>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

This is what the result is supposed to look like. It does actually look like this, until I start to resize the Path. Then the path overlaps ontop of the bottom textbox only. The rest are fine

#### Expected result

[image]

#### Actual result

[image]

Am I using the canvas dependenct properties wrong?

### Update

I moved everything in to a DockPanel instead like suggested in the comments but end up with the same result.

This is the style that I am using for the Grid containing the StackPanels

```
<Style x:Key="ShapeInputStyle"
       TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="-10 -10" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=controls:DesignerItem}}"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=controls:DesignerItem}, Path=IsSelected}"
                     Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The result of this change looks like the following photo. So you have some back history, this was my original problem I was trying to solve in the SO post linked to above. The end resolution was putting the StackPanels in the canvas and it is what fixed my problem below problem. It worked fine in canvas's for everything but the bottom canvas.

### Update 2

I followed the answers provided, but have undesirable results (actually I had this exact same problem in my OP last night at one point as well). You can see in the image, that the shape starts out to small. In the link I provided above where i got the sample project, this template is used both in a toolbox for the user to select and on a canvas for rendering/editing. if I set the minwidth/height then it distorts in the toolbox. Also, the adorner surrounding the entire template is not ideal, as it would be preferred if the adorner only surrounded the shape like it does when using canvases.

Any other ideas?

#### Replacing canvas with DockPanels

[image]

#### Wireframes now encompass the entire dockpanel.

[image]

Comment: Seems to me a `Canvas` is not an appropriate container for that. Looks more like a `DockPanel` to me.

Comment: A dock panel was the original container, but the Path always rendered above all of the docked elements. The ultimate solution in the SO post I linked to, was to go with this approach in order to keep the Path from rendering over my other elements around the path within the template. I also used a grid that was sliced up but the Path always rendered over the entire grid, and would never remain constrained to the row/column I assigned it

Comment: Seems to me that would be caused by which UI element you're setting the Attached Property `MoveThumbTemplate` on. I think you should try again with the DockPanel, while leaving the attached property in the square path.

Comment: I tried that just now (see my updated OP) and it has the same end result. The path overlays on top of the bottom stackpanel

Comment: Dude, remove all those `Canvas`es. either use nested `DockPanel`s or place each TextBox and TextBlock in a `StackPanel`.

Comment: Ug how did I mess that up. I'll revise that when I get home and post back.

Comment: So I swapped the canvases out for DockPanels. The end result is shown in the picture above, which is what I was trying to solve last night originally. The resolution was wrap them in canvases, which worked fine for all but the bottom stack panel.

Comment: That dock panel usage is completely wrong.

Comment: @MeirionHughes an example of how you think they should be used to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

this is the bottom panel

```
    <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Canvas.Bottom="-40"
                    Canvas.Left="-20">
            <TextBlock Text="Height"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox />
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
```

changes:

- `VerticalAlignment="Center"` to `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` in canvas
- added `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` in canvas
- set `Canvas.Bottom="-40"` in stackpanel

result

[image: result]

---

**TIP**

likewise you created a style for `ShapeInputStyle`. You can also wrap your extra elements into a control template to make it reusable too

control template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditableSides"
                 TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ShapeInputStyle}">
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Canvas.Top="-40"
                            Canvas.Left="-20">
                    <TextBlock Text="Length"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox />
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Canvas.Left="-40"
                            Canvas.Top="-20">
                    <TextBlock Text="Height"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox />
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Canvas.Right="-40"
                            Canvas.Top="-20">
                    <TextBlock Text="Height"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox />
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Canvas.Bottom="-40"
                            Canvas.Left="-20">
                    <TextBlock Text="Height"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox />
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

usage example

```
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource EditableSides}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource Decision}"
              ToolTip="Decision">
            <s:DesignerItem.MoveThumbTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Path Style="{StaticResource Decision_DragThumb}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </s:DesignerItem.MoveThumbTemplate>
        </Path>
    </ContentControl>
```

Comment: You are always welcome. I added a tip to make the whole stuff reusable, that will help you reuse the same without redefining whole structure. good luck, happy coding :)

Comment: I am going to have multiple shapes, and I need to have the values bound to a model that is associated with each shape. Is it bad practice to have my ControlTemplate try to bind to the parent data context, or should I take this in a different approach?

Comment: it is not a bad practice to bind to parent data context, all you need to do is to think carefully. You can make use of attached properties if needed. You may post your idea on code review site, let's see if it is good or it needs any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (basic dock template)

```
<DockPanel Width="200" Height="200">
    <TextBlock Text="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Center" Width="150" Height="150" Background="#FFEC7900"></TextBlock>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<DockPanel>
   <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
       <TextBlock Text="Length"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
       <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Height"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Height"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Height"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>

    <Path Style="{StaticResource Square}"
          x:Name="path"
          ToolTip="Decision">
        <controls:DesignerItem.MoveThumbTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Path Style="{StaticResource Square_DragThumb}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </controls:DesignerItem.MoveThumbTemplate>
    </Path>
</DockPanel>
```

Other than that, see [WPF Layout Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans).

Comment: Please see my Update #2 in the OP